# Alexandrov's generalization of Cauchy's rigidity theorem

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, polyhedra, rigidity

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(geometry)#Generalizations_and_related_results) that A. D. Alexandrov generalized *Cauchy's rigidity theorem for polyhedra* to higher dimensions.

The relevant statement in the article is not linked to any source. The sources at the end of the Wikipedia page seem to be only about $3$-dimensional polyhedra as well, in particular Alexandrov's book "Convex polyhedra".

> Where can I find a reference for that statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is Theorem 27.2 of Igor Pak's book [Lectures on Discrete and Polyhedral Geometry](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/book.htm) (which in general is a very nice resource for these sorts of questions):

> Let $P,Q\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ (or $P,Q \subset S^d_+$), $d\geq3$ be two combinatorially equivalent (spherical) convex polyhedra whose corresponding facets are isometric. Then $P$ and $Q$ are isometric.

(Here $S^d_+$ is a d-dimensional hemisphere.)

Comment: And Corollary 27.3 (p.256) is: Every convex polytope $d \ge 3$ is rigid.

Answer (score 5):

This may help:

> Bauer, C. 
>   "Infinitesimal Rigidity of Convex Polytopes."
>   *Discrete Comput Geom* (1999) 22: 177. https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00009453

"Aleksandrov [1] proved that a simple convex $d$-dimensional polytope, $d \ge 3$, is
infinitesimally rigid if the volumes of its facets satisfy a certain assumption of stationarity.
We extend this result..."

[1] is the 1958 *Convex Polyhedra* book.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure, does infinitesimal rigidity imply global rigidity?

Comment: @M.Winter: Not always, but I believe in this case *Yes*.

Comment: However, this is not a generalization of Cauchy rigidity theorem, but rather an infinitesimal version of a theorem by Minkowski on existence and uniqueness of polytopes with given facet volumes and normals. Minkowski proved global rigidity.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia is correct. This is discussed in Alexandrov's book "Convex polyhedra" in Section 3.6.5.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the hint. I looked it up. I would probably not have recognized this short paragraph as a proof of the generalized theorem. Anyway, Wikipedia should link this statement to this source more directly.

Comment: @M.Winter Wikipedia is, as the name suggests, a wiki ;) - so it's everyones job to make sure mistakes or oversights are corrected. Why not add the source reference yourself ?

Comment: @Torque Actually, I thought about it. ;) But as everything that is public and not completely obvious how to do right, I hesitated. I will see what I can do!